# When enter trackbar value = change the ProgressBar value using a button like this

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

```
TrackBarvalue = ProgressBar Value
```

Using button to make sure A == a = b

Get one value as another value as =
like a = 10 b = 20 a = a + b

[image: For Doing Like This]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int A = trackBar1.Value;

    if (trackBar1.Value == A)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (A);
    }
    else
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (20);
        MessageBox.Show("Try again !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Decide what language this relates to and remove other language tags. Don't try to trick people into viewing your question when it's irrelevant to them.

Comment: If you just set the `Value` of a `TrackBar` to `A`, what possible use could it be to then check whether it's equal to `A`? I have no idea what problem you're actually trying to solve. You need to provide a better explanation.

Comment: WHat is `A`, `a` and `b` and what does `A == a = b` mean since it is a conditional and not an assignment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve, and how the button interacts with the other UI elements.

IF you want to respond to the trackBar movement then use the `.Scroll` event

```
    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int A = 50;
        if (trackBar1.Value == A)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = A;
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 20;
        }
    }
```